# Inconsistency in GET BUCKET request

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm noticing differing results when listing the contents of folders within the same bucket, specifically, sometimes the *home* folder will be listed under the 'Contents' section (within the *key* element), but other times not. See the following two outputs:

**This output does not include the prefixed directory**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns='http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01'>
<Name>
test22</Name>                            <=== Bucket
<Prefix>
16-Jul-2013</Prefix>                     <=== Prefixed folder
<Marker>
</Marker>
<IsTruncated>
false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
<Key>
16-Jul-2013/0371.txt</Key>               <=== ONLY OBJECTS LISTED
<Generation>
1374016944689000</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>
1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>
2013-07-16T23:22:24.664Z</LastModified>
<ETag>
"5d858b3ddbf51fb5ec4501799e637b47"</ETag>
<Size>
96712</Size>
<Owner>
<ID>
00b4903a97d860d9d5a7d98a1c6385dc6146049499b88ceae217eaee7a0b2ff4</ID>
</Owner>
</Contents>
```

**But this output does**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns='http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01'>
<Name>
test22</Name>                            <=== Bucket
<Prefix>
22-Aug-2013</Prefix>                     <=== Prefixed folder
<Marker>
</Marker>
<IsTruncated>
false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
<Key>
22-Aug-2013/</Key>                       <=== FOLDER INCLUDED IN LIST
<Generation>
1377178774399000</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>
1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>
2013-08-22T13:39:34.337Z</LastModified>
<ETag>
"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
<Size>
0</Size>
<Owner>
<ID>
00b4903a97d0b7e1f638009476bba4c5d964f744e50c23c3681357a290cb7b16</ID>
</Owner>
</Contents>
```

Both requests were made with the following code (note I did not use an authenticated session, the items are pubilc-readable):

```
uri = URI('https://storage.googleapis.com/test22?prefix=16-Jul-2013')     <=== prefix changed for each case
req3 = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

#req3['Authorization'] = "#{token['token_type']} #{token['access_token']}"
req3['Content-Length'] = 0
req3['content-Type'] = 'text/plain - GB'
req3['Date'] = Time.now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
req3['Host'] = 'storage.googleapis.com'
req3['x-goog-api-version'] = 2
req3['x-goog-project-id'] = ###############

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') { |http|
   resp3 = http.request(req3)
   puts resp3.body.gsub(/>/, ">\n")
}
```

Why the difference? Is there something basic I'm missing?
Thanks in advance...

-Lee

Comment: Can you please show us the API requests you used in both cases? (Please strip out the Authorization: header)

Comment: Is it possible that you have an object in your bucket named "22-Aug-2013/", with a slash?

Comment: API request attached. Regarding having an object named same as the directory no, I did check that. These are not the only two directories that behave this way, there is another that also shows the homedir though that one is empty, but the one in the sample output above was not.

Comment: I think it's likely that somewhere along the line an object with "22-Aug-2013/" was created, because GCS stores Generation only for objects (not prefixes) and a Generation is clearly being returned. Two questions to help understand that: First, in your comment, you mention that the sample output was not an empty directory. Did you mean that there are objects such as 22-Aug-2013/somefile.txt that did NOT get listed? Second, in the above example, if you do a GET on "storage.googleapis.com/test22/22-Aug-2013/"; what data do you see returned?

Comment: Travis, thanks for following up, regarding your questions: 1) No, all objects that are stored are in fact listed, what I meant to say is that this strange behavior doesn't seem to correlate to empty directories (or folders as GCS may call them).  I'm not sure what to say other than I'm looking at the cloud console and can verify that folder 22-Aug-2013 is empty and a listing of all objects in the folder includes the folder name under the <key> attributes (as attached above) and a similar listing for folder 16-Aug-2013 still does not list the folder under <key> unlike its sibling...

Comment: ...Regarding your second question: 1) a listing of .../22-Aug-2013/  returns HTTPForbidden 403  and 2) a listing of .../22-Aug-2013 returns HTTPNotFound 404

Comment: A 403 on "22-Aug-2013/" is further supporting evidence that the object "22-Aug-2013/" does indeed exist.  It seems that you don't have read access to it, thus the 403.  Possibilities here include the default object ACL for the bucket not granting you read access, or an object owner changing the ACL.  Assuming you have write access to the bucket, can you try deleting the "22-Aug-2013/" object?  This will confirm without a doubt that it did exist and then we can try to narrow down how it got created in the first place.

Comment: ok, just to prove I wasn't going crazy I did the following. From the google cloud console I created a new folder named '30-Aug-2013', then modified my script above to list said folder and still get the empty folder listed in the <key> attributes. Furthermore, if I repeat the GET object calls I also get the 403 and 404 as before. At this point I'm 100% confident that what I'm seeing is not an artifact of earlier actions since I started from scratch

Comment: You are definitely not crazy, this is a seam in trying to represent a flat namespace in a hierarchical way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a folder using the Cloud Console, it creates a placeholder object with the name of the folder + '/' to represent the empty folder.  Even if you later add objects to the folder, the placeholder remains.

On the other hand, if you directly upload an object with a '/' in the name using the API (for example an upload to 'folder/object.txt') no placeholder object is created because the presence of the object is enough to infer the existence of the folder.  If you delete 'folder/object.txt', the folder will no longer be listed in the root listing of the Cloud Console as there is no placeholder object.

To answer your question explicitly, that means that '16-Jul-2013/0371.txt' was created via a direct upload to '16-Jul-2013/0371.txt'.  By contrast, '22-Aug-2013/' was created by the New Folder button in the Cloud Console.  In the latter case a placeholder object is created, in the former, it is not.

All of this is because the GCS namespace is flat, not hierarchical.  The folder abstraction is there to help you visualize things hierarchically, but it has some limitations.

Comment: A most excellent explanation, it also explains why the 'inconsistencies' I saw. Thanks!!!